# Jquery autocomplete menu issue

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

Jquery autocomplete menu issue

When navigating up and down in the menu on the autocomplete with key-up and key-down and at the same time have the mouse pointer hovering one suggestion it's resulting in two suggestions is highlighted at the same time.

This could be confusing for the user so i need a way to handle this scenario. Ehter the mouse or the keys should have precedence over the other.

Any suggestions on how to handle this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us a live demo? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ <- here I see that when you navigate with the arrows the selection made by hovering the mouse is overridden by navigating with the keys. (And that how most people handle this problem -> see google, bing, firefox, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I found i had following css on the page, and when i removed that it works. .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a:hover {
            background: #BCD2EE;            
        }